# How to do a SPICE DC simulation with capacitors and get the correct final voltage?

Tags: capacitor, simulation

I have a circuit with a capacitor attached to the output node.

If I do a transient simulation, I can see the output voltage slowly rise until it reaches its final value.

I am trying to find the parameters that give me the output voltage that I desire. I was thinking I could do this by looping through the circuit with various parameters and looking through the output file for the configuration that gives me the best values.

Since I am only interested in the final DC voltage, I thought I could do an operating point simulation. However, the voltage returned is not the final one.

I think the the simulator is replacing the capacitor with an open-circuit and solving for the circuit for that. I wonder if there's a way to get the correct output voltage using DC simulation.

Comment: *I have a circuit...* Then **show it** a simple screenshot is already way better than nothing.

Comment: This question is akin to, "I have a car. It doesn't work right.  What's wrong?"  Please add more detail, like a schematic, plots, etc.

Comment: Not quite, see the circuit image in the comment to Simon Fitch's answer. Also, the OP's simulation problem is quite generic, and the question, while not complying to strict SE standards, still makes sense and can be answered. At least, some hints can be indicated.

Comment: If all of the settling times are similar, have you tried using a .measure probe near the final time? Also, you asked about why .12v is dc, you can see this is the first step of your transient analysis since ltspice finds dc op first for transient.

Answer (score 3):

Capacitors don't have any influence on the "final voltages" of a circuit. A DC operating point analysis does indeed treat capacitors as open circuits, and inductors as short circuits. If you removed all the capacitors from the circuit, and repeated the analysis, you would find the exact same "quiescent" potentials everywhere.

The operating point of a circuit could be described as a steady state in which all capacitors have charged to their "final" voltage, and no further current flows through them, and all inductors have completely established and steady magnetic fields, with zero volts across them.

In other words, if no current is flowing through any capacitor, and the circuit is in a stable and settled "steady state" you could then remove all capacitors, and nothing would change.

Of course the term "steady state" is important here - if the circuit has elements with instability, such as oscillators or integrators, then you can't have a steady state, and there will always be potentials and currents changing somewhere. In such a case, there's no "quiescence" and we can't make these assumptions.

Take these three circuits, one without any capacitor, the others with capacitors in different positions. If you removed all capacitors, all three would be identical.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fffOX6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here's a transient (time domain) simulation showing this behaviour:

[image]

As you can see, all three circuits converge to the same DC operating point after some time, regardless of the presence of capacitors, or where those capacitors are placed.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'm using a switched capacitor working as a resistor. Have a look at this circuit. https://i.imgur.com/v6qTM0B.png. I'm using the capacitor to filter the output. From the simulation, the output voltage settles around 0.25V. If I do a op simulation, I get a value of 0.12V. Why am I getting 0.12V instead of 0.25V?

Comment: @LeonhardEuler Probably because .op uses a convergence algorithm like Newton Raphson to detect when it's "arrived" at some steady state, unaware that very shortly afterwards some oscillator in your circuit is about to throw a cat among its pigeons. This is just a an educated guess, but the problem is, as I explained, there's no steady state in your circuit, no "quiescence", and therefore no DC operating point....

Comment: @LeonhardEuler I believe the best you can do is a long-term time domain (transient) analysis, and observe behaviour after all capacitors have settled at their long-term average DC charge. The simulator has no way of knowing how far in the future that will occur. It surprises me that you get a result at all from a DC OP analysis, with so many voltages flapping around forever.

Answer (score 0):

The circuit can have multiple quiescent points, and capacitors do have influence on probability of a circuit to arrive at a certain quescent point at power start-up. Take, for example, two inverters with one's output connected to the other's input and vice versa (bistable circuit). In fact, many non-trivial circuits with non-linear components have multiple quiescent points.

When simulating a multicomponent nonlinear circuit, the Newton method used in .tran analysis can converge very slowly or even not at all. A modified nodal analysis performed on this circuit gives a system of nonlinear algebraic equations. Alternative numerical methods for solving these equations (and consequently this circuit) are [homotopy methods](http://eaton.math.rpi.edu/CSUMS/Papers/Homotopy/4C-2.pdf). Homotopy methods are implemented in SPICE simulators like [Cadence's Spectre](https://www.cadence.com/en_US/home/training/all-courses/86172.html) and [OrCAD PSpice](http://www.sfu.ca/%7Eljilja/cnl/projects/Homotopy/).

I don't know what homotopy method is implemented, if any, in LTspice. Documentation states that the simulator tries a number of methods to find an operating point. You can control this process disabling a particular method with an .options directive, see http://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/_OP_Find_the_DC_operating_point.htm.

Of the methods listed in this reference, Pseudo Transient looks most similar to direct solving of MNA's nonlinear algebraic equations. Try and disable the other options and see if the results are in agreement with your expectations. If not, you need to use a simulator that guarantees global convergence by supporting homotopy methods.